# Caching ruby gems locally on demand for many rails developers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, proxy, rubygems

We are in a teaching environment with up to 100 students working simultaneously on Rails projects with limited bandwith to `rubygems.org`.  Our environment is primarily a Redhad/Debian Linux lab with shared file space mounted by many separate client boxes.  Simple `bundle install` takes too long; hangups are too frequent at certain times of day.

So we are looking for the best way to cache gems *on demand* locally "inside" our enterprise firewall and proxy.  Ideally this will be transparent to the students: `bundle install` will "just work" with nothing special in the Gemfile.

Google turns up several suggestions with no clear favorite.  At present we are looking at [this Nginx-based idea](https://gist.github.com/1218276/851c1b43f219f23f5847747fb68b74a2970268bd).  Before going down that road (we have no current Nginx experience), are there better alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Any properly configured proxy server would do the job, but personally I'd set `:path` option for each prospective gem in `Gemfile` to point to some shared network volume like NFS share. Then update it with rsync from one master machine which is allowed to pull gems rubygems.org .
As a side note, bundler has *--local* option to install command to retrieve gems from locally stored cache only. However don't find it too useful in this case.